# How to remove property from objects inside array in react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to remove a property from objects inside an array in the React state?

I am getting the error:

> Kim.tsx:150 Uncaught TypeError: documents.forEach is not a function

Code:

```
  // Function to remove Mark as Reviewed property from objects inside the document array
  public hideMarkAsReviewed() {

      // Creates new array of objects
      let documents = {...this.state.documents};

      // Deletes property from all objects in array
      documents.forEach(d => { delete d['Mark as Reviewed'] });

      // Updates document state with the object
      this.setState({documents: documents});

  }
```

Comment: `Object.keys(documents).forEach....`

Comment: On your case you tried to iterate over object. To make it possible, you need to use Object.keys first

Comment: or you need to create a new array instead of new object. `let documents = [...this.state.documents];`

Comment: What is inside the `this.state.documents`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can delete particular property for all objects in array.

```js
let array = [{name: "this is name1", title:"This is title 2"},{name:"this is name2", title:"This is title1"}];

let newArray = array.map(function(item) { 
    delete item.name; 
    return item; 
});
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is where you're getting confused:

```
      // Creates new array of objects
      let documents = {...this.state.documents};
```

It does not create a new array of objects, it creates an object of objects, where the keys are would-be indexes.

```
      // Creates new array of objects
      let documents = [...this.state.documents];
```

Arrays use square brackets, and the Array type does have the forEach prototype.

Answer (score 1):

the only way is to use filter to remove elements from your array for example

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
```